# How to use coroutines GlobalScope on the main thread?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to use the latest coroutines in 0.30.0, and having trouble figuring out how to use the new scoping.  In the original coroutines I could set the context with UI or CommonPool and everything worked correctly.

Now I'm trying to use the GlobalScope in my ViewModel while reading from a room database, and then I want to assign the value returned to my LiveData object.

I'm getting the following error when I try to set the LiveData value

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke setValue on a
>   background thread

```
fun getContact() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val contact = contacts.getContact() // suspended function
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { phoneContact.value = contact }
        }
    }
```

I only see Default, Unconfined and IO for dispatchers, and none of them work, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?  Where is my option for the Main Thread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was missing the Android portion of coroutines in my gradle file

> implementation
>   "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.30.0"

Once I had that, Dispatchers.Main appeared

Comment: Not for me. I have that in my gradle file already but `Dispatchers` is still red.

Answer (score 40):

You solved your immediate problem by adding the dependency, but let me add a note on your usage of `GlobalScope`.

Using the `GlobalScope` in production code is an antipattern. It's there for similar reasons like 
`runBlocking`, to make it easy to do quick experiments. You should especially avoid it on Android due to the complicated lifecycle of app components.

If you're launching a coroutine from an Android event handler, you should use the current Activity as its coroutine scope. This will ensure your coroutine gets canceled when the activity gets destroyed. Without that the coroutine will go on, referring to the now-dead activity.

Here's a sample adapted from the [documentation on `CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/-coroutine-scope/index.html), it shows how to use your activity as the coroutine scope:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    // Sets up the default dispatcher and the root job that we can use to centrally
    // cancel all coroutines. We use SupervisorJob to avoid spreading the failure
    // of one coroutine to all others.
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext =
            Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob()

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        coroutineContext[Job]!!.cancel()
    }

    // this.launch picks up coroutineContext for its context:
    fun loadDataFromUI() = this.launch {
        // Switch to the IO dispatcher to perform blocking IO:
        val ioData = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // blocking I/O operations
        }
        draw(ioData) // use the data from IO to update UI in the main thread
    }
}
```

If you're using a `ViewModel`, use it as the scope and cancel the master job from `onClear`.

If you're doing work from a background job, use your `JobService` implementation as the scope and use `onStartJob` and `onStopJob` the way we use `onCreate` and `onDestroy` above.

Comment: I'm running the coroutine from my ViewModel so isn't the global scope okay since the ViewModel isn't tied to the life cycle?  For example, if I'm downloading data, the download will continue even if I've left that activity, and when it finishes LiveData will get updated.  The next time I return to the activity, it will subscribe to the LiveData and updated accordingly?

Comment: Just adding a note - this is my first time using MVVM and LiveData so I could be wrong in what I said above.

Comment: Haven't used MVVM so I don't know the details on its threading model. But you shouldn't use `GlobalScope` in any case. At least you should use a coroutine scope tied to the `Application` instance and it should specify `Dispatchers.MAIN` as the default. Without that you're forced to write `launch(MAIN)` everywhere to start a UI coroutine.

Comment: I'll keep looking into that further, but using the Application scope sounds like the right way to do it in this case.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Ben987654 - This might be late, but if using coroutines from the View Model you should tie it to the view model lifecycle. Override onCleared of the View Model and cancel the job there. That way you won't need an application level scope and you won't be leaking.

Comment: It's not too late, it's just a side project I work on here and there.  So with no onCreate I'd just create the job in init {} and cancel it in onCleared() otherwise it's the same as the above answer?

Comment: Where does `CoroutineScope` from? I can't figure out what to import to stop it showing red.

Comment: @hippietrail 
`implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1'`
`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1"`

Comment: @MahmoudShahoud: Thanks. It turned out to be [a bug in Android Studio](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80089849) that sometimes makes it red even when you've done everything properly. Lost a whole day chasing that.

Comment: What about if I have a fire-and-forget kind of request? I don't necessarily have to use `GlobalScope` but it makes sense there, right? Otherwise, what would you recommend there?

Comment: @stdout On Android, most use fire-and-forget use cases are background services that continue to run when the app is in the background, or operations that must complete gracefully and not be subject to sudden termination. You have to use `WorkManager` for them. So I guess you'd use a GlobalScope coroutine only if you have a process that must run just while the app is being actively used, but doesn't interact with the GUI.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Exactly. Having this task executed is not quite "important" when the process dies.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik There are some things that need to be done in the background, but I don't want to create a whole service for that. For instance, I want to delete the instance ID of Firebase. I now use GlobalScope.launch for this because it needs to be off the main thread.